# Test sofware for SQL injection

Tags: sql, oracle, security, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

We have to work with older version of an ERP system (1993).

It has multiple modules. These modules have windows(tabs). Tabs have cols (obviously).

In this tabs the USER can make a "new column" -> it's like a subquery. Query can be used only in parentheses ().

I'm just curious, is it possible to make an injection by user.

e.g.:

```
 --basic query (self join)
(select i.my_col from my_table i where my_pk = i.pk)

 --illlustrating
(select replace(i.my_col, 'UPDATE...') from my_table i where my_pk = i.pk)
```

Is there any way to make the second query workable ? I mean, can the user somehow update columns whit this method ?

How can i test it ?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.
Are you saying that the UI of this off-the-shelf ERP system allows end users to add subqueries to pre-defined queries, and specify the SQL for those subqueries, in order to add more information to the UI?
What is the underlying database engine? If Oracle, which version - if the ERP is from 1993, is the RDBMS equally ancient?

Comment: The overall description is pretty vague and it's mixing widgets with database entities (if a Window tab *obviously* has columns, then it's likely a table rather than a tab) but if, as you suggest, the user can actually type SQL code then SQL Injection, bug or not, is certainly a builtin feature. I think this question could use some additional info, perhaps even a couple of screenshots.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: To be clear: are you asking if it's possible to run a SELECT statement which executes an UPDATE statement as a column in its projection?

Comment: @APC in this case, yes. If is it possible, they have to "revoke" a few priviliges from the users. That's the reason, why would it great to test it.. if it works, that's a big risk, i think.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic values can be handled for `where` condition through `preparedStatement` and `setParameter` however unfortunately that option is not available for dynamic `column` selection.

The best thing can be done is to have all possible/applicable column names before you pass to the query.

```
// check if my_col is possible values else throw the error.
(select replace(i.my_col, 'UPDATE...') from my_table i where my_pk = i.pk)
```

Comment: I don't think *"unfortunately"* is the right word here. The Seeker is asking whether it's possible for a bad actor to hijack the SELECT to execute a malicious UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding SQL injection is down to the mechanism which turns the user's input into executable statements. The actual example you posted won't run, but I can think of ways it might be possible to hijack the SELECT to run malicious DML. It depends on the framework: given that the underlying software is ancient I suspect it might be extremely vulnerable.

Generally speaking, if you're worried about SQL Injection you should investigate using Oracle's built-in [DBMS_ASSERT package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#ARPLS231) to verify your SQL strings. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2)